# Encoding JSON as an object, even when it has a zero-index

Tags: php, arrays, json, associative-array

I have an array that might look something like this:

```
array(
  1 => "foo",
  4 => "bar"
)
```

When I `json_encode` it, it turns out something like this:

```
{
  "1": "foo",
  "4": "bar"
}
```

That's exactly how I need it.

However, there is the possibility that the array would look like this:

```
array(
  0 => "baz"
)
```

In which case I would want the JSON to end up like this:

```
{
  "0": "baz"
}
```

But instead, it ends up like this:

```
[
  "baz"
]
```

Is there any way I can force the JSON encoder to assume that this is an object instead of an array?

**EDIT**: Sorry, I simplified it for this post, but I realise now it's quite important: This array is nested in another array, which must be an array, **not** an object.

**EDIT 2**: Example of this:

```
array(
  0 => array(
    0: "baz"
  ),
  1 => array(
    4: "bar"
  )
)
```

needs to become:

```
[
  {
    0: "baz"
  },
  {
    4: "bar"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
$test = array(
  0 => array(
    0=> "baz"
  ),
  1 => array(
    4=> "bar"
  )
);

$json = json_encode($test, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

var_dump($json);
```

Available since PHP 5.3.0.

Comment: That appears to have no effect, for me.

Comment: If you are using 5.3.0+ use this (which hopefully you are) if not, then my answer should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, it does actually work, I think… still testing.

Comment: @JJ56 Please, if you find one of the answers helpful, you should upvote and accept it.

Comment: @teo Sorry, I was asleep. Timezones and all that.

Answer (score 0):

Cast it to an object first:

```
<?php
$array = array(
  0 => "baz"
);

echo json_encode((object)$array);
?>
```

Outputs:

```
{"0":"baz"}
```

EDIT:

```
<?php
$array = array(
  0 => array(
    0=> "baz"
  ),
  1 => array(
    4=> "bar"
  )
);

$array = castOnConsecutiveRecursive($array);
echo json_encode($array);

//json_encode acts as you want unless the array is consecutive from 0, so if that's the case then we have to cast it
function isConsecutive($array){
    $lastIndex = null;
    foreach($array as $key=>$value){
        if(is_null($lastIndex)){
            $lastIndex = $key;
            if($key !== 0)
                return false;
            continue;
        }
        if($lastIndex !== $key+1)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function castOnConsecutiveRecursive($array){
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            $array[$key] = castOnConsecutiveRecursive($value);
            if(isConsecutive($value))
                $array[$key] = (object)$value;
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
?>
```

EDIT 2:
Doh, didn't see that option in the documentation, use `teo`'s answer if you are using PHP 5.3.0+

Comment: Great idea, thanks! However, I forgot to mention, this array is actually embedded in another array, which must be an array, not an object. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: @JJ56 Can you show me an example of what you mean so I can answer more fully?

Comment: Yes, don't use PHP. The whole array/dictionary duality quite rightly is a source of immense frustration for many, and has only marginally benefitial uses cases.

Comment: @David-SkyMesh I wish it were possible, but this is an existing codebase, which I need to update. I am planning a NodeJS rewrite eventually, but it's not coming any time soon.

Comment: Basically, given an unknown heirarchy of arrays (some may be associative), it's not possible a priori to determine how they will serialise to JSON. It's not just data-dependent, it's library dependent.

Comment: Not true, you can easily loop through the master array and cast all internal arrays to objects, it's slower than a normal json_encode, but it works fine.

Comment: Why would you cast *all* internal arrays to objects? Are they all definitely going to be non-associative arrays? Fail.

Comment: Added an example to the question of the actual situation. It would be great to have a solution which works for any hierarchy of arrays, some arrays and some objects, however.

Comment: Show me one example where it would fail and I'll agree, but until then I think it would work perfectly fine.

Comment: Given the edit of the question, you *could* just cast the inner arrays. But that doesn't stop PHP being a crappy language for JSON serialisation.

Comment: @JohnV Any case where you have an unknown nesting of associative and non-associative arrays. You can only make a guess as to whether a particular "array" is supposed to be associative or not. You have to be aware of the intent of the data-producer to determine whether you need to cast the contents of the data-structure before serialisation.

Comment: @JohnV Yes, your suggestion does answer the revised question, definitely provide an answer. But do you understand why that doesn't work in the general case?

Comment: I'll have a sample that will work in even an unknown nesting, it will take a minute though.

Comment: If you can find an array that this won't work for let me know, I'll improve it (but from what I tested it works). At the very least it should work for your case.

Comment: @JohnV That just guesses at intent. The heuristic you're using is simply "if the keys are numeric, consequetive, and start from zero, then assume it's non-assiciative". It's still just a guess though... counter-example incoming...

Comment: I based the answer off of the fact that json encode changes the encode if it is a consecutive array starting from 0. (Although it seems there is a built in option just for this, woops!)

Comment: @JohnV understood, but that doesn't change the *unresolvable* problem with the language or your solution (as generally applied). Still working on counter-example.

Comment: Counterexample: You're implementing a JSON "echo & sort" service that also adds a key "__sorted_keys" to the top-level JSON element with the value set to a sorted list of all `object` keys encountered within the decoded object-heirarchy. The sender sends you `{ "stuff" => [1,2,3,{"0"=>"Hello","1"=>"There"}]}`. Your solution will treat the naiive decoding of that that innermost array as non-associative, and so you'll produce the wrong result.

Comment: Which part would be considered non-associative exactly? I'm using strict comparisons so the "0" and "1" won't be considered numbers...?

Comment: The point is extremely simple. It's not possible to tell the difference (in PHP) between the deserialisation of `{ "0" => "Foo", "1" => "Bar" }` and `["Foo","Bar"]`. They're different things, and no amount of guessing in your code will get it right. Even if you use flags to force it one way or another, you can still be given an input that gives an incorrect deserialisation output, based on the intent of the data-producer. On that basis, you're making potentially invalid assumptions about the data-structure you'll be handed for encoding *to* JSON.

Comment: The associativity (or not) is either a *convention* or an internal optimisation artefact of PHP (both are possible). You're still making potentially invalid guesses about the data-producer's intent. See above counter examples. When you say "considered non-associative", you're making judgements on behalf or the data-producer.

Comment: I'm not guessing, because of the strict comparisons they are clearly different to the function.

Comment: strict and potentially incorrect! PHP doesn't store the string `"0"` and the number `0` differently on deserialisation of a JSON heirarchy. There's no way for you to correctly guess (even with strict comparison) which it should have been.

Comment: If you completely avoid using PHP's `json_encode` and `json_decode` it's possible to construct a "valid" de-/serialiser. The problem is that in serialisation it needs to be restricted to *real* PHP objects, and only non-associative PHP arrays for inputs, and throw exceptions when given otherwise. The deserialiser then creates real PHP objects from JSON objects and PHP arrays from JSON arrays.